# Best way to import lots of subclass?

Tags: java, import, subclass

I'm currently working on a turn base roguelike
And I'm gonna use a lot of subclass for monsters,tiles and items
So far all I do is import them one by one with "import a.b.c;"
Is there a way to put all the subclass in 1 Java file and import them all at once or should I just import them line by line?

Comment: line by line, you may use `a.b.*`.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be hard-coding the subclasses anyway. There is a dynamic nature to games, so you would want to load the particular "Monster" when appropriate. You would most likely interact with an interface `Monster` rather than any specific one.

Comment: Also, consider: _When you find yourself with a lot of subclasses, that often means a data-driven approach is better. Instead of lots of code for defining different powers, try finding a way to define that behavior in data instead._ (Nystrom, _Game Programming Patterns_)

Comment: I agree with @KevinO, and your question appears to be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) type question where you ask how to fix a ton of imports when the **real** problem that needs fixing is a poor design.